# SSDT no avaible input column error

Tags: etl, data-quality-services

i am learning SSDT from this link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819740(v=sql.120).aspx
on point 8 i stuck
before that i install DQS successfully and also connected to Data Quality service client 
now when i check in MS SQL 2014 there is 3 database created DQS_MAIN,DQS_PROJECT,DQS_STAGING_dATA

now when  i follow point 8 and click on mapping tab this shows an error 
[image]

any solutions please?

Comment: I use this data for excel 

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIZWq.png